# Send packets from a specific interface in c

Tags: c, sockets, network-interface

I've been doing some socket programing in c and I would like to let the user of my program specify the interface to send and receive packets from. The linux man page for [socket(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) says that you can set the socket option SO_BINDTODEVICE to bind the socket to a particular device such as "eth0". It also occurred to me that when calling bind() you typically pass it a sockaddr_in struct with the sin_addr.s_addr property set to INADDR_ANY to tell the socket to bind to all interfaces as shown below

```c
int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

struct sockaddr_in local;

local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
local.sin_port = 0;

bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof local);
```

If the point of passing in the sockaddr to bind is to specify where to bind the socket locally on your machine, could you just pass in the IP address of a specific interface to bind your socket to it? I was hoping someone could clarify what the socket is doing here, and what the difference is between that approach and using `setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &devicename, sizeof devicename);` before you bind.

Note: In the example above I used UDP and removed error checking for simplicity, Ideally the answer to the above question should be able to work independently of the protocol being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the point of passing in the sockaddr to bind is to specify where to
>   bind the socket locally on your machine, could you just pass in the IP
>   address of a specific interface to bind your socket to it?

Binding to an address (via `bind()`) and binding to an interface (via `setsockopt()`) serve different, but overlapping purposes.  Usually `bind()` is what you want.

In particular, your question seems to assume that there is a 1:1 mapping between addresses and interfaces, but that it is not a safe assumption.  One interface can have multiple addresses, and, at least in principle, one address can be served by multiple interfaces.